# Value of type 'MKAnnotation' has no member 'latitude'

Tags: mapkit, swift2, xcode7

I updated XCode to 7 and BAM.. lots of errors.

One of which is that annotations no longer have latitude and longitude members.  This worked like a charm prior to updating so I am confused as where to go with this.

The problem here is that I am looking at all the annotations on the current map and trying to filter for specific latitude and longitude locations that are already pinned on the map.

```
var existingPins = self.mapView.annotations.filter {m in m.latitude == getLocation.latitude!  && m.longitude == getLocation.longitude! }
```

I have to think there is another angle that I am not familiar with to get at those coordinates.  I will continue searching but any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MKAnnotation` is a protocol, so whatever type you have implementing that protocol is likely whatever was providing the latitude method. The `MKAnnotation` doesn't include a `latitude` method, but it does require a `coordinate` method, which returns a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, which *does* include a latitude member.

Without seeing your code, my guess is you have two options:

1. Change the `m.latitude` call to `m.coordinate.latitude`.
2. Use the `as?` or `as!` operators to get the annotations as whatever custom type you have that is actually implementing `MKAnnotation`.

Comment: Yep.. I just posted the answer below, coming to the same conclusion you did.  Thanks Arclite.

Answer (score 2):

Never fails, I spend hours scratching my head, I post the question and I figured it out a few minutes later.

The "m" is a specific annotation and I needed to specify the coordinate member which has within it the lat/lon.

Also, I needed to cast my passed-in values as doubles so that I can compare them.  I am not sure how this worked prior to xcode 7.

here is the modified code.

```
let existingPins = self.mapView.annotations.filter {m in m.coordinate.latitude == Double(getLocation.latitude!)  && m.coordinate.longitude == Double(getLocation.longitude!) }
```